# Slim C/C++ REST-Server library without dependencies

Tags: c++, c, web-services, rest

In an safety critical embedded environment (in terms of MISRA) I want to provide services accessible via JavaScript (the script itself is not safety critical, btw). So I'm currently looking for a lightweight C/C++ library which provides REST-server functionality with as few dependencies as possible (STL is ok).

I had a look at some projects which seem to be quite mature:

- https://gitlab.com/eidheim/Simple-WebSocket-Server
- https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp
- https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk
- https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib
- https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed

and the examples listed [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12006/fast-and-secure-c-webservices-library)

.. but nearly all of them need Boost for `asio` or standalone `asio` at least, which is not an option for me. Poco has no dependencies but it's quite large..

The less features the better - all I need is to send / receive some JSON strings.

Comment: libcurl could handle the requests and responses but does not itself implement a server.